# Stuck compressed piston on a Clarks Skeletal Hydraulic Brake

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I've opened up the reservoir and tried resetting the piston on the bleed nipple side and it won't budge. I haven't ridden this bike for about a year and the front wheel was off, and I also noticed when I was getting it out that the bleed nipple cover had come off/been taken off of the bleed nipple (if that's any contributing factor to the compressed piston).

Does anyone know what I need to do about this? I've tried a few times to open up the reservoir and them push the piston back with quite a lot of force and no results. It's pretty far out too, the pad sits a few millimetres off of the side where the pin is located, and the tire can't spin at all and doesn't sit completely in between the pads (they end up at a V shape because the pad is being pushed out by the piston but is still magnetised to it).

It's also just the one piston, the other is perfectly in place.

Also, I just pinched this picture off of their website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGlX2.png
Just to reaffirm, the picture isn't my brake, but the brake pad indicated to by the red arrow is the brake pad that is not sitting properly and it being pushed out by a compressed piston.

Comment: Note that from your description it's unclear whether you're talking about a caliper or a brake lever.  (But I'm guessing you're talking about a caliper and you made the mistake of removing the wheel and not placing a spacer in its place.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually something is pretty broken when pistons are this stuck and can't be moved even with the bleed port open.

Taking apart the caliper is probably the next step. Whatever is making it stuck or obstructed, there's probably not another way of getting access to it. Despite the mystique, most calipers are pretty simple inside.

Comment: Okay, will do. Is there any decently priced bleed kits that you know of? I don't have one yet, and I guess this will give me an excuse to buy one.

Comment: I have no idea what the brake you have needs in terms of fittings. Might warrant some research. For the kind of random, non-major-brand brakes, the main kits I've used are the Jagwire Pro ones, which do work and tend to have whatever you need, but they're kind of completist and pricey too. I don't have much experience with other similar ones.

Comment: Okay, will have a look. Thanks for the help.